# Custom GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I'm trying to design a `Layout` wich is like this image :

[image]

I thought that the best way would be using `LinearLayout` for each item, and I was wrong, because it looks like this :

[image]

And the problem is the `ImageView` that is not in the middle, I tried to put it with margins, but when I try to launch this APP on a Samsung s2 it mess the `Layout` and on my Lg g3 the `ImageView` I see on the bottom (without margin) and on s2 I see it on the middle...

This is my `layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardElevation="5dp"
android:layout_margin="7dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/LinearImageView">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
  </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/LinearImageView"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LinearTitulo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SOME TEXT HERE"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LinearPrice"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearTitulo">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
            android:text="SOME TEXT HERE"
            android:layout_below="@+id/info_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/LinearPrice"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I thought that a `GridView` would be the point, and I saw a library like [`AsymmetricGridView`](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView) but it's not what I need because you put it by code (java), and I don't want it.

I suppose that is a `GridView` with two columns, the first column has 2 rows and the second has one row, but I don't know if it's the best approach, could you guide me?

Comment: It's a ListView, with a custom row: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another layout without fussing with Relative positioning. I use a similar layout in one of my apps and it works fine, though you'll probably want to season to your own taste ;)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Edit: added pic of output

[image]

Comment: Can you post the output please?

Comment: The ImageView's size is debatable. You don't want an image whose width is 40dp for a device's screen width of 500dp(e.g).

Comment: True, though the OP's ImageView is even smaller. The layout can accommodate larger/smaller sizes and both the TextViews also center vertically if their accumulated height < the ImageView. It's been working fine for me, best of all (IMO) no RelativeLayout hassles ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_holder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/LinearImageView"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="80">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text 1"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:textSize="40sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text2"
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_armchair"
                android:layout_weight="20"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: Rendering]

Comment: it's API 23 actually... will the API be an issue ?

Comment: I will lower the the API level to 17 & I'll see what happens.

Comment: No, i could do that if my minsdk is 17 but I want to be 15

Comment: @Skizo it works just fine on API 15. Check my update image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95386/discussion-between-jdev-and-skizo).

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/LinearPrice"` and add `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to your ImageView

Answer (score 1):

How about this as a reference:

[image]

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#111">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="TextView1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="TextView2"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/placeholder_loader"
            />
    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want the image centered between the two texviews

Comment: Its not at the end as i posted

Comment: the layout is similar
do you want the image be placed dynamically in between the TextViews not giving the size?

Comment: Check It Again, The image is now at right most of layout